# jdb stop at given line or method

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

As a CLI-inclined programmer, I'd like to ask  if the Java command line debugger JDB is capable of running from current position and stopping at given line?

For instance,

```
200   public Trade create(TradeCreateReq req) {
201        validatePayments(req);
202 =>     Trade t = new Trade(OutBizType.of(req.getOutBizType()), req.getOuterId());
203
204        buildItem
205            .andThen(buildBuyer)
206            .andThen(buildToAddress)
207            .andThen(buildInvoice)
208            .andThen(buildPayTools)
209            .accept(req, t);
210
211        if (!t.isSecured())
212            t.setSecured(true);
213
214        return t;
215    }
```

I'd like to advance to line 211 with a single jdb command rather than typing 7 'next' commands or set break point at 211. A cursory look at the 'step', 'next', 'cont' does not give me the answer.

I know the Perl CLI debugger can this job nicely with 'c' command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Run to cursor" is just a high level debug command composed from:

- set breakpoint (stop at file:line)
- continue
- clear breakpoint

See there's no disable breakpoint or disable when count times reached, those are high level debug commands a debug cli should compound and keep in memory.

More info on available commands on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html

You can compound easily those commands on a vim plugin like

https://github.com/yuratomo/dbg.vim/blob/master/autoload/dbg/engines/jdb.vim

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the way to set breakpoints in JDB is inconvenient as Java class name is usually lengthy and I have to clear the breakpoints afterward.

Comment: Non sense by just pasting the ~official~ document which really sucks with very poor readability.